# I have a switchcase for my buttons in onClick but both activities are starting

Tags: java, android

I have a switch case in my onClick handler where I want each of my buttons to start different activities when clicked. But the problem I am getting is, when I click Imagebutton1 which is person1(AmyProfile Activity), both of the activities are starting. So I am getting JohnProfile Activity on top of AmyProfile Activity. Instead I should get just AmyProfile Activity.

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

    public HomeFragment(){}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

        ImageButton person1 = (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.person1);
        ImageButton person2 = (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.person2);
        person1.setOnClickListener(this);
        person2.setOnClickListener(this);

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch(view.getId()) {
            case R.id.person1:
                Intent intent1 = new Intent(view.getContext(), AmyProfile.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent1, 0);
            case R.id.person2:
                Intent intent2 = new Intent(view.getContext(), JohnProfile.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent2, 0);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should have received a warning with this code, giving you clear guidance as to what would happen due to missing a `break` statement and allowing the `switch` to fall through. Have you checked the warnings?

Answer (score 3):

You should add break after the case end

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch(view.getId()) {
        case R.id.person1:
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(view.getContext(), AmyProfile.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent1, 0);
            break ;
        case R.id.person2:
            Intent intent2 = new Intent(view.getContext(), JohnProfile.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent2, 0);
            break ;
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow can't believe I forgot the break statement. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

dude add `break;` statement into your switchcase

Comment: @Krumia - Don't be too hasty - this IS an answer to the question.

Comment: However, you might want to add a snippet of code to illustrate

Comment: @RobBaillie: I personally feel that an answer needs some work behind it. If an answer is this trivial, I feel that it should just be a comment.